# What part of garment is this?

Tags: kill-la-kill

Senketsu, Matoi Ryuuko's full-life-fiber uniform has this peculiar element on it that looks like an eyepatch:

[image: the element in question with a phat red arrow pointing at it]

The eye-like orange-red element on our right is a part of the scarf, but what is the black, grey-crossed eyepatch-like element on the opposite side?

Comment: Senketsu taking look me into the eyes to a whole new level ( couldnt help mysef :))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from episode 24...

> When Senketsu transforms into Senketsu Kisaragi after absorbing everybody else's life fibers, we witness his right eye *opening* rather than becoming *uncovered* ([gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vYUJ.gif)). This suggests that Senketsu was, initially, "blind" in his right eye before receiving enough life fibers to fix that, or something, and hence, that the eyepatch-like element on Senketsu's right is probably in fact just Senketsu's eye scarred shut.
>
>  It's not clear to me at this point how this relates to the notion that Senketsu is modeled after Matoi Isshin, given that Isshin wore an eyepatch over his right eye, but was probably not blind in that eye (judging from his face when he, as Souichirou, got out of the bodybag - [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqLKR.jpg)), unless whatever he did to change his appearance (plastic surgery perhaps?) blinded him.